# How to populate data in a one to many relationship between two forms when the target form's table has no matching entry?

Tags: ms-access

This is probably a dumb question, but I'm a noob, so forgive me. I have two tables with a one to many relationship based on a OrderNumber. Essentially, I have some order details in one table, including OrderNumber (the one side of the relationship) and I am trying to get a list of LotNumbers in the other table using the OrderNumberLot (the many side) to link them together, as there can be many lot numbers on one order. The primary key in tblOrderDetails is OrderNumber and the primary key in tblLotNumber is LotID (auto number), but the linked field is OrderNumberLot. I made a open form button located on frmOrderDetail to open frmLotNumbers (based on the tblLotNumber). The deal is when frmLotNumber opens the OrderNumberLot field is blank. I understand there is no associated record in tblLotNumber, because I am trying to enter it, but how do I get the OrderNumber from the previous form, frmOrderDetail, with the button to automatically populate in the OrderNumberLot field in frmLotNumbers?  I certainly don't want people to have to type it, because they will screw it up as badly as I have this explanation of my question! Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Build form/subform arrangement. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-form-that-contains-a-subform-264731d6-ca69-4204-94d8-c266fe084102?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with June7 on using a subform-approach for your purpose.
If you already have created the form, you could simply drag it from the sidebar onto your mainform and set the "Link Master Fields" and "Link Child Fields" to "OrderNumber" and "OrderNumberLot" - or you just use the subform-wizard and follow its instructions.

Though, some people dislike subforms in general and try to avoid them whenever possible - which might make sense at further stages of development. Instead of subforms, you could then use vba to transfer information from one form to another.
Lets say your button is named bt_openform

```
Private Sub bt_openform_Click()

'Open the desired form. The option "acFormAdd" forces the form
'to add a new entry whenever loading and requerying.
'As we want to add a new record, we will not use the filter settings
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmLotNumber", , , ,acFormAdd

'Next, store information from the initial form into the newly opened form
'To refer to data from the current form (meaning the one, in which the Sub is triggerd),
'you can use "Me.fieldname" and to refer to another form, use "Forms!formname!fieldname" 
Forms!frmLotNumber!OrderNumberLot = Me.OrderNumber

End Sub
```

You could also do it the other way around and retrieve the information when loading the form:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

Me.OrderNumberLot = Forms!frmOrderDetail!OrderNumber

End Sub
```

To be on the safe site, one might want to nest this function in an if statement, to check whether frmOrderDetail is open or not. This way, you can open your frmLotNumber from different forms without causing troubles

```
If CurrentProject.AllForms("frmOrderDetail").IsLoaded Then Me.OrderNumberLot = Forms!frmOrderDetail
```